# Error with SQLite query, "sqlite3.Cursor object"

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

I've used github .db file viewer online and the query found below works, but the query in python doesn't work. When I run the code below I just get the error:

> sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x036CA0E0

Here is my code:

````
def Search_Crash_Police_Region():
  query_region = ("SELECT * FROM demographics WHERE Crash_Police_Region = '?'")
  region_results = tkvar_Crash_Police_Region.get()
  cursor.execute(query_region.replace("?",region_results))
  results = cursor.execute(query_region)
  print(results) ```
````

Answer (score 2):

cursor.execute() return a cursor, here's how to get the data:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I used a similar way to fix it. Thanks.